# Is it possible to combine asynchronous and synchronous services in one gRPC server?

Tags: grpc

Or can I use a pair of server/client to handle synchronous requests and another pair to handle asynchronous request？ I'm just starting working on a distributed project which implements gRPC. I should have multiple database nodes and each should be able to send RPC to another. I have to allow both synchronous and asynchronous RPC here. One for general request and another one for 2 phase commit. But the gRPC tutorial does not mention if I should combine two services in one server and leave them separately. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what exactly you want to achieve.
If you want to have two gRPC services living in a single server, the answer is YES.

Define two sets of service definitions `ServiceA.proto` and `ServiceB.proto` and implement both in your server.

Comment: I was thinking about creating both a synchronous and asynchronous services on a single server thread, but now I feel it may better for each service to lie on each thread.

Comment: right, I don't recommend to manage the thread by yourself unless you know what you're doing.